# <form> and </form> tags printed in php do not align properly

Tags: php, html, forms

I'm creating a list of clients and their details, which are imported from the database. At the end of every row, there's an 'edit' button which will display all the information about that client in a form, which is to be edited.

As the client list is imported from database, I've written the form in PHP as following-

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {   
            echo"   <tr id=".$count.">";
            echo"       <form method='post' id='edit_form' action='search_client_details.php?edit=true'>";
            echo"       <td><input type='checkbox' id='chkStatus' name='customer' class='chkbox'  value='".$row['client_id']."'></td>";
            echo"       <td>".$row['client_name']."</td>";
            echo"       <td>".$row['client_address']."</td>";
            echo"       <td>".$row['client_type']."</td>";
            echo"       <td><input type='submit' name='submit' id='edit_form_submit' value='Edit'  class='btn btn-success' style='background-color:#27ae60; color:#fff'></td>";
            echo"       </form>";
            echo"   </tr>";

            $count++;
        }
```

It prints the list properly. But when the edit button is pressed, it does not work. Inspect element on a row shows this-

```
<tr id="1" style="display: table-row;">     
<form method="post" id="edit_form" action="search_client_details.php?edit=true"></form>     
<td><input type="checkbox" id="chkStatus" name="customer" class="chkbox" value="1"></td>        
<td>Name</td>       
<td>address</td>        
<td>type</td>       
<td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="edit_form_submit" value="Edit" class="btn btn-success" style="background-color:#27ae60; color:#fff"></td>
```

As you can see, the form tags are printed first and then the rest. Why is this  happening? I'm a beginner at this, all help is appreciated.

Comment: why you put form tag inside while loop ?? if u want to delete particular record then it is easily achieved by edit button ..

Answer (score 2):

It happened because you create the `<td>` element immediately after the opening of form's tag. Your html markup is invalid. Consider this two lines :

```
echo "<form method='post' id='edit_form' action='search_client_details.php?edit=true'>";
echo"<td><input type='checkbox' id='chkStatus' name='customer' class='chkbox'  value='".$row['client_id']."'></td>";
```

You see the second line having another opening `td` element which is invalid in this case

**Added**

If you want the whole submitted, you must use array for element's name. Put the form's tag opening outside of table, and closing form's tag after table's closing tag.

```
<form method='post' id='edit_form' action='search_client_details.php?edit=true'>
<table>
 .... any markup
<?php
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
    {   
        echo"   <tr id=".$count.">";
        echo"       <td><input type='checkbox' id='chkStatus' name='customer[]' class='chkbox'  value='".$row['client_id']."'></td>";
        echo"       <td>".$row['client_name']."</td>";
        echo"       <td>".$row['client_address']."</td>";
        echo"       <td>".$row['client_type']."</td>";
        echo"   </tr>";

        $count++;
    }?>
</table>
    <input type='submit' name='submit' id='edit_form_submit' value='Edit'  class='btn btn-success' style='background-color:#27ae60; color:#fff'>
</form>
```

Then later in server side `search_client_details.php`, you can use `for` loop to iterate all the code :

```
for( $i = 0,$length = count($_POST['customer']); $i < $length; $i++ ) {
   echo $_POST['customer'][$i]; // this will show all the data sending from form
   // do the operation here
}
```

Comment: What if I gave the form tag for the whole tr? Or is it just invalid to have a td tag inside a form tag?

Comment: Yes, it's invalid markup anyway. But you can have it inside td like  so : `<td><form>some elements</form></td>`

Comment: But I need the whole row submitted. Any way to do this in JavaScript or JQuery?

Comment: that's why i ask him why to put form tag inside while loop :) thanks for sharing such a valuable knowledge :)

Comment: Worked! Thank you! You are right, it was just over-complicated by me...

Comment: Glad to hear that, after all we're all learning. Anyway, you're welcome mate.

Answer (score 1):

You cant add form in tr attribute. Instead of it you can carete new table within existing and assign it to form

try this:

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
        {   
            echo "   <tr id=".$count.">";
            echo "       <td><form method='post' id='edit_form' action='search_client_details.php?edit=true'><table><tr>";
            echo "       <td><input type='checkbox' id='chkStatus' name='customer' class='chkbox'  value='".$row['client_id']."'></td>";
            echo "       <td>".$row['client_name']."</td>";
            echo "       <td>".$row['client_address']."</td>";
            echo "       <td>".$row['client_type']."</td>";
            echo "       <td><input type='submit' name='submit' id='edit_form_submit' value='Edit'  class='btn btn-success' style='background-color:#27ae60; color:#fff'></td>";
            echo "</tr></table></form></td>";
            echo "</tr>";

            $count++;
        }
```

Comment: This has worked. Now I need to redesign the table in css as each row has a different width. Thanks! 

But I still wonder exactly why is it not allowed to have a td or tr tag inside a form...

Comment: It just like a cup of coffee. If you mixed those with salt, chili sauce, it will get extremely bad taste! :)

Comment: actually, due to wrong html, your form get closed before the elements of your form generated